# sql group rows by column

Tags: sql, group-by, rows

I have a table:

```
ID    Status    Date
1     Stop      01.01.2001
1     Run       02.01.2002
2     Stop      03.01.2003
2     Run       04.01.2004
```

and I'd like to group rows as follow:

```
ID    Stop         Run    
1     01.01.2001   02.01.2002
2     03.01.2003   04.01.2004
```

What is the best way to make this group?

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,
       max(case when status = 'Stop' then date end) as stop,
       max(case when status = 'Run' then date end) as run
from your_table
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to get the output using

### CASE and GROUP BY

```
select ID,
 MIN(case when action = 'Stop' then dateval end) STOP,
 MIN(case when action = 'Run' then dateval end) RUN
from my_table
group by id;
```

In order to use GROUP BY, you need to use some aggregate function. So, you can use either MIN or MAX

---

**QUERY WITH TEST DATA:**

```
with my_table as
(
    select 1 id,      'Stop' action,       '01.01.2001' dateval from dual
    union 
    select 1 id,      'Run' action,       '02.01.2002' dateval from dual
    union 
    select 2 id,      'Stop' action,       '03.01.2003' dateval from dual
    union 
    select 2 id,      'Run' action,       '04.01.2004' dateval from dual
)
select ID,
 MIN(case when action = 'Stop' then dateval end) STOP,
 MIN(case when action = 'Run' then dateval end) RUN
from my_table
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

### PIVOT function of ORACLE

, the same can be done using below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ID,dateval,action
        FROM   my_table)
PIVOT  (max(dateval) FOR (action) IN ('Stop' AS STOP, 'Run' AS RUN));
```

---

**QUERY WITH TEST DATA**:

```
with my_table as
(
select 1 id,      'Stop' action,       '01.01.2001' dateval from dual
union 
select 1 id,      'Run' action,       '02.01.2002' dateval from dual
union 
select 2 id,      'Stop' action,       '03.01.2003' dateval from dual
union 
select 2 id,      'Run' action,       '04.01.2004' dateval from dual
)

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ID,dateval,action
        FROM   my_table)
PIVOT  (max(dateval) FOR (action) IN ('Stop' AS STOP, 'Run' AS RUN));
```

Comment: I catch an error with IN statement: "Incorrect syntax near '1'. Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID, or '.'."